Why is trapz returning negative values, even when x is sorted ascending and y is all positive?
y = np.array([59817478.73563218, 56195352.29885057, 59679547.70114943,
       61071789.08045977, 56678110.91954023, 56900812.06896552,
       61942478.73563218, 57360582.18390805, 57423800.57471264,
       61169490.22988506, 58930984.48275862, 56777248.85057471,
       60586156.89655172, 59669490.22988506, 55715467.24137931,
       60485582.18390805, 61771501.72413793, 56966904.02298851,
       60666616.66666666, 56887881.03448276, 60699662.64367816,
       61545927.01149426, 56418053.44827586, 58850524.71264368,
       61071789.08045977, 57018628.16091954, 57936731.60919541,
       62103398.27586207, 58135007.47126437, 56629260.34482759,
       61922363.79310345, 59757133.90804598, 56195352.29885057,
       60400812.06896552, 61711156.89655172, 56942478.73563218,
       60438168.3908046 , 61416616.66666666, 57703972.98850574,
       59380697.12643679, 62241329.31034483, 59031559.1954023 ,
       58037306.32183908, 61216904.02298851, 61757133.90804598,
       56735582.18390805, 58390754.59770115, 62216904.02298851,
       58216904.02298851, 57432421.26436782, 61956846.55172414,
       60350524.71264368, 61123513.21839081, 58541616.66666666,
       56939605.1724138 , 60958283.33333334, 59976961.49425288,
       56489892.52873563, 59129260.34482759, 60981271.83908046,
       57620639.65517242, 58264317.81609196, 61824662.64367816,
       57709720.11494253, 56376386.78160919, 60249950.        ,
       59544490.22988506, 56629260.34482759, 59455409.77011494,
       61320352.29885057])

x = np.array(['1900-01-01T04:39:51.596000000', '1900-01-01T04:39:53.873000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:39:56.124000000', '1900-01-01T04:39:58.403000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:00.655000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:02.904000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:05.182000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:07.435000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:09.714000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:11.962000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:14.213000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:16.495000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:18.745000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:21.025000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:23.275000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:25.525000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:27.804000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:30.115000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:32.362000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:34.613000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:36.895000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:39.146000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:41.423000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:43.676000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:45.926000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:48.203000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:50.455000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:52.736000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:54.986000000', '1900-01-01T04:40:57.235000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:40:59.517000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:01.767000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:04.046000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:06.297000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:08.547000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:10.827000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:13.078000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:15.357000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:17.605000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:19.854000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:22.138000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:24.387000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:26.668000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:28.918000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:31.168000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:33.448000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:35.698000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:37.978000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:40.228000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:42.479000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:44.758000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:47.069000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:49.319000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:51.569000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:53.849000000', '1900-01-01T04:41:56.099000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:41:58.378000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:00.629000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:02.876000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:05.159000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:07.410000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:09.690000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:11.940000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:14.190000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:16.471000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:18.720000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:20.997000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:23.251000000',
       '1900-01-01T04:42:25.500000000', '1900-01-01T04:42:27.781000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')

np.trapz(y, x) => numpy.timedelta64(-9204159157384838832,'ns')

Both scipy.integrate and np.trapz give negative values.

After investigating, found integer overflow error. Hope this helps someone else.

The default (and most capable) float data type in numpy is numpy.float64 which is limited to values lower than 2^(64-1). You are unlucky here because the last values overflow.
If you plot the trapezoidal integral np.cumsum((y[1:]+y[:-1])/2 * np.diff(x)):

You could just change units (say divide y by 1000) and the numbers will look better.
